# Jquery text and form submit on click inside a specific div class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I have a php `foreach` that generates divs with class `.like-button1,2,3,4..` and generate more forms `form1,2,3,4..`.

The goal is that when users click on "like" the div shows the text message:

"You like: www.facebook.com/ferrari"

The script works correctly but the `.hover` function is not what I really want, because if you click on the first like in the `like-button1` div and you go on the second div, the text message appears on that second div.

I can't find a right way to identify the right div, if you click the like inside div with class `like-button1` show text message and submit the form in that div, without possibly avoiding the script just hovering an other div.

Thanks to all.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {

  $(".like-button1").hover(function() {                    
      $(".like-button1").text('Ti piace: ' + response);
      $("#form1").submit();
  });

  $(".like-button2").hover(function() {                    
      $(".like-button2").text('Ti piace: ' + response);
      $("#form2").submit();
  });

  $(".like-button3").hover(function() {                    
      $(".like-button3").text('Ti piace: ' + response);
      $("#form3").submit();
  });

});
```

Comment: No idea what you are asking, rephrase entire question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rather than using unique classes you can do this:
add to the divs a new attribute called `data-target=""` with the id of the form to submit.
i.e.

```
< div class="like-button" data-target="form1" >< /div>
```

then the javascript will look like this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
  var formId = $(this).attr('data-target');
  $(".like-button").text('');            
  $(this).text('Ti piace: ' + response);
  $("#"+formId).submit();

});
```

This will clear the text from all classes .like-button and add text to the one that was clicked. the submit the form with the id passed in the `data-target=""` attribute.

writing your code this way will also shorten the amount of code you write now and in the future since you will undoubtedly be adding more like divs in the future

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, on my confused question... your code works well just doesnt resolve the main problem, I mean, how can I identify the right form without using the hover function.. since more "like-buttons" divs are generated by the foreach a user can hover an other div and send the wrong form.